# how to remove space between letters in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, vba

I have few numeric columns which I got from a website and copied directly into Excel.

In those columns there is a SINGLE Leading space at the beginning of each number in the cell of the entire column.

try provide vba or any excel formula

Comment: did you try =VALUE(mid(A1,2, len(A1)-1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()
Selection.Replace " ", ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the `Trim()` worksheet function?